# How can I connect iPhone and web service and get XML data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, cocoa-touch

I know how to connect to web server using an iPhone but now I have to connect the iPhone to a web service. I don't know how to do it and there is no demo or class available online.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The link that amrox provide, [SOAP Web Services](http://icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/), does answer all the stuff that you asked for.

Comment: @vavdiya: can you tell me how to connect to a web server to parse retrieve an API?

Comment: You can refer this blog,  http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.in/2011/04/working-with-webservices.html

Answer (score 20):

You might find this tutorial, called Intro to [SOAP Web Services](http://icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/) useful.  He shows how to package a request, send it to a web service, and read the response.

If you need some help with XML parsing, there is the [TouchXML](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML) library which will give you a nice xml "document" to work with.  Just be cautious of memory usage.

If you have to parse large XML message this [tutorial about libxml and xmlreader in Cocoa](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/08/18/cocoa-tutorial-libxml-and-xmlreader/) will show you how to parse XML with the lower-level event-style parsers.

Answer (score 16):

I've created an open source application for iPhone OS 3.0 that shows how to use REST & SOAP services in iPhone application, using XML (using 8 different iPhone libraries), SOAP, JSON (using SBJSON and TouchJSON), YAML, Protocol Buffers (Google serialization format) and even CSV from a PHP sample app (included in the project).

http://github.com/akosma/iPhoneWebServicesClient

The project is modular enough to support many other formats and libraries in the future.

The following presentation in SlideShare shows my findings in terms of performance, ease of implementation and payload characteristics:

http://www.slideshare.net/akosma/web-services-3439269

Answer (score 12):

You can use these 2 lines which return the response of your HTTP request. You don't need any configuration. This code is usefull if you try to access a PHP scritp for example. After you just have to parse your result.

```
NSURL *URL=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:stringForURL];
NSString *results = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL :URL];
```

Comment: As long as the script returns quickly, because this code creates a synchronous request that blocks the current thread (which might be the UI thread, and that's a really bad idea). Use async connections whenever you can. http://akos.ma/_pp0

Comment: As Adrian Kosmaczewski mentions, this code creates a blocking call, which will effectively lock you application up.  Definitely go with asynchronous calls if you can.

Comment: And what about dotnet web service?

Comment: As long as you have an URL, it's fine! As @akosma mentioned, it's only for test purpose because it's synchronous. Then you'll implement other way to access to the data

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you have two options :

- Use a third party library. You can try [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/).  It didn't work for me, but it is under active development so it improves every day.
- Use a raw HTTP connection and handle every request/response. This is the way I followed. It is hard, so I'd also like to know a better approach.