# can i able to call web services from my iphone application instead of retriving the data from database?

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone development.previously i have retrive the data from database...
I want to know can i able to call web services from my iphone application or not...

if there is a possiblity to call the web services from my iphone Application plz give me the detail explanation ....

how can i call the web services from my iphone App?

Thank u...

Comment: plz reply me as soon as possible...

I'm waiting for ur reply...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Web Service from iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018369/accessing-web-service-from-iphone)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352676/how-can-i-connect-iphone-and-web-service-and-get-xml-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call web services.  How you do so depends exactly on the web service.  To download data, you can use [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) or a related class.  If the data is JSON, you can then use a library such as [TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON) to interpret the data.  If it's XML, you can use [TouchXML](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML) or the native libxml.