# Tutorial about web service

Tags: iphone, web-services, xcode, ios4

Can anyone give me good tutorial about web service?
 i find below tutorial with example but doesn't work

[1](http://icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/)
[2](http://grabalife.com/2009/10/19/using-net-web-services-and-dataset-objects-in-your-iphone-app/)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352676/how-can-i-connect-iphone-and-web-service-and-get-xml-data)

for example if i want to show weather in my app should i get data from specific web site or i can get data from yahoo or other site about weather

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SajjadZare,

I answered a similar question on SO and wrote a blog post about consuming Web APIs.  Please let me know if this doesn't help you:

[How to Consume JSON or XML Web APIs on the iPhone](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/10/15/how-to-consume-json-or-xml-web-apis-on-iphone-smoothly/)

[The original SO question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883747/returning-data-from-data-grabbing-class-from-web/)

Cheers and best of luck,

Mark

Comment: Imagine that i want to get news from a website what should i send for the request?