# xml parsering from webserver in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

To all
I am trying to parser the xml in my project But I have the code for xml parsing for locally I want the server base xml parsing how can i pass that

This is my  xml parsing link i want to use:

http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,50500000,30500000

This my xml parsing for calling local file how can I call my webserver xml link for parsing.I need different-differnet type of calling xml link for parsing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    _forecastInfo=nil;
    currentcond=nil; 
    forecastcond=nil; 
    // Pass the NSData to the parser whether its from local file or its coming from web.... NSString *fileName=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"weather" ofType:@"xml"]; 
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileName]; 
    ForecastInfoParser *parser=[[ForecastInfoParser alloc]init]; 
    parser.delegate=self; 
    [parser parseData:data]; 
}
```

Comment: You see this link,
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352676/how-can-i-connect-iphone-and-web-service-and-get-xml-data

Comment: I done with praser it also value show on console And it also display on the cell but after 1 second it get crash And showing exce_bad_exce

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"hhttp://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,50500000,30500000"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

// 2 -- parsing
parser = [[MyParser alloc] init];

[parser parseXML:data];
```

Comment: IS that we have to use only this much .Or we have to open connection and closed that also is needed or not

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *URL=@"http://www.google.com";
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
NSError *err = nil;
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &resp error: &err];
NSString * theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
[resp release];
[err release];
NSLog(@"response: %@", theString);
```

Comment: I that any other way to do that @ios Developer

Comment: Another way is to use RESTKit, or ASIHTTPRequest Framework for this purpose.

Comment: NSString *URL=@"http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,50500000,30500000";   NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURLNSURL URLWithString:URL]];   NSURLResponse *resp = nil;   NSError *err = nil;   NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &resp error: &err];   NSString * theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; [resp release];[err release];   NSLog(@"response: %@", theString);   ForecastInfoParser *parser=[[ForecastInfoParser alloc]init]; parser.delegate=self; [parser parseData:response];

Comment: Is there something printed on console, the response string ?

Comment: i have tested this piece of code and its working with your URL, i think there might be some problem in your parser.

Comment: NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURLNSURL URLWithString:URL]]; this line has problem in you code. Copy the same code as given in answer, you problem will be removed.

Comment: I done with praser it also value show on console And it also display on the cell but after 1 second it get crash And showing exce_bad_exce