# iPhone - java networking service?

Tags: java, javascript, iphone, objective-c, tcp

I am looking for some kind of tutorial which will help me make an application which would connect to the server on the computer and would respond as soon as the app is launched like would print out Hello World or something. I know one of doing this is bonjour programming but I am not really sure how I would connect to a server made in Java..So I am looking for some kind tutorial which would let me achieve this or if possible you could help me give a kick start....

thanks, 
TC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from another discussion similar to yours. It might be able to help you
[How can I connect iPhone and web service and get XML data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352676/how-can-i-connect-iphone-and-web-service-and-get-xml-data/2464815#2464815)

If your server returns XML and your iPhone app parses it and creates/populates views based on it then it should not matter what language your server is using,